# NSCoding Persisting UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have seen different question on stackoverflow related to this topic. Some says that `NSCoding` does not conform with `UIImage` and other says that with iOS 5, it does conform.

I want to persist images in my app. I am using `encode` and `decode` methods and everything (title, labels etc) are persisting but NOT the images.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:creator forKey:@"creator"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:pubDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
  //  [aCoder encodeObject:thumbnail forKey:@"thumbnail"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail) forKey:@"thumbnail"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setTitle:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"]];
        [self setLink:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"link"]];
        [self setCreator:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"creator"]];
        [self setPubDate:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"pubDate"]];
        [self setThumbnail:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];        
    }
    return self;
}
```

I am also using `UIPNGRepresentation` but its not working. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: firstly.. you must use the same key "thumnail" or "thumbnail" :)

Comment: I'm usign… simple.. "… encodeObject:image forKey …"  where image is UIImage variable

Comment: my "Class" - http://pastie.org/5682577

Comment: @TonyMkenu using simple encodeObject:image is also not working thats why i have commented that out in the code.

Answer (score 7):

You're not encoding an image. UIImagePNGRepresentation() returns an NSData object. NSData conforms to NSSecureCoding. I haven't worked with that before, but the docs say that you have to decode it like this:

```
id obj = [decoder decodeObjectOfClass:[MyClass class] forKey:@"myKey"];
```

**After Edit:** The above doesn't appear to be necessary. I used the following code in a test app, and both approaches to encoding and decoding an image worked.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"personName"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.image2 forKey:@"thumbnail2"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image1) forKey:@"thumbnail"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setName:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"personName"]];
        [self setImage2:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail2"]];
        [self setImage1:[UIImage imageWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As Aleph said, the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I have also used "[self setThumbnail:[UIImage imageWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];" but thats also not working

Comment: This is not fully encoding and decoding the UIImage because it is not encoding and then decoding the UIImage.scale property.

Comment: You can use 
imageWithData:scale: for that purposes

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:creator forKey:@"creator"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:pubDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);
    NSLog(@"Data length: %d", data.length);
    [aCoder encodeObject:data forKey:@"thumbnail"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setTitle:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"]];
        [self setLink:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"link"]];
        [self setCreator:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"creator"]];
        [self setPubDate:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"pubDate"]];
        NSData* data = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSLog(@"Data length: %d", data.length);
        [self setThumbnail:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];        
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: just tried the code you provided. It didn't work. To my surprise, the data length in the console is zero.

Comment: Is it zero when encoding? Try logging the thumbnail object.

Comment: I have used "NSLog(@"Data length 1: %d", data.length);" in encodeWithCoder and NSLog(@"Data length 2: %d", data.length); in initWithCoder. Both logs gives '0' in console

Comment: If you get 0 on encoding that means that either the image is nil or it is failing to encode as PNG. Check that you have a valid image on encode. If you encode 0 bytes you will, of course, get 0 bytes on decode.

Comment: If i remove the cache by resetting the content, the first time it fetches new entries, images does show in the tableview but when i fetch it again and it fetches the entries from the cache, then it does not show images which means the images are not nil, its failing to encode them and i don't know why.

Comment: logging just thumbnail is giving NULL. What should i do now?

Comment: If your image is nil then you have a problem somewhere else. Maybe create a new question and post more code.